# Exterior hose bib ID and parts

Tags: exterior, plumbing-fixture, hose

I cannot seem to find a replacement valve stem that fits my 2 exterior hose bibs. The stem at the washer is very bad and I can't remove the handle for replacement.
These are about 44 years old and the home is in the Tidewater Virginia area.

Comment: What's your question? Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Honestly, after 44 years, it'd be OK to just replace the entire thing. You could get an upgrade with a 1/4 turn handle and a frost-proof valve, even. The amount you save in the time & effort to find repair parts would more than make up for the cost of the new bib.